# Cannot build ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build ios with this command :

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

yet it renders me this error :

```
An error occurred while running subprocess ng
```

I'm using ionic 4

Any clues please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove platform iOS and add it :

```
cordova platform rm ios

cordova platform add ios
```